# Child Themes of Non-Wordpress Sanctioned Templates

Tags: child-theme

I have created and used over a dozen Wordpress child themes for various websites. I have downloaded the themes from Wordpress. This time I wanted to use a theme outside of Wordpress' realm. I heard good things about Gridly, actually it was part of Lynda.com's presentation.

When I tried to create a child theme for Gridly, I approached it in the same manner. I set up the usual directory and css files with the correct info at 
the top. I imported all the original theme's style.css. I activated my new child theme.

Despite all of that I still can't use custom CSS. In fact, when I use Chromes Dev tools and inspect where an element is getting its styling from, it comes from the parent theme's stylesheets. When I inspect the header it calls for

```
<?php if ($gridly_color_scheme == 'dark') { ?>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?    >/css/dark.css" /> 
<?php  } elseif ($gridly_color_scheme == 'custom') {  ?>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/css/custom.css"/> 
<?php  } else {?>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/css/light.css"/> 
<?php  } ?>
```

I have don't know if that `get_template_directory_uri();` is getting the parent or child theme's uri.

Can anyone shed any light on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` and `get_stylesheet_directory()` for Child Themes

Use `get_template_directory_uri()` and `get_template_directory()` for Parent Themes

Thus making your function:

```
<?php if ($gridly_color_scheme == 'dark') { ?>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?    >/css/dark.css" /> 
<?php  } elseif ($gridly_color_scheme == 'custom') {  ?>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/css/custom.css"/> 
<?php  } else {?>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/css/light.css"/> 
<?php  } ?>
```

...subtle difference which can be easy to miss.

Helpful resources:

- http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_stylesheet_directory
- http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_stylesheet_directory_uri
- http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_directory
- http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_directory_uri